# How to get the column names after table extracted from a PDF file using camelot? I'm new for this

Tags: python-3.x, python-camelot

Briefly I am doing this steps.

```
tables = camelot.read_pdf(doc_file)
tables[0].df
```

I am using `tables[0].df.columns` to get column names from the extracted table.

But it does not give the column names.

Comment: Basically, from what I gather camelot extracts data from a pdf and creates a pandas dataframe.  tables is therefore a pandas dataframe and you would employ ```tables.columns``` to get a list of these names you can either use ```tables.columns.to_list()``` or ``` list(tables.columns)```

Answer (score 2):

Camelot extracted tables have no alphabetic column names.

`tables[0].df.columns` returns, for example, for three columns table:

```
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)
```

Instead, you can try to read the first row and get a list from it: `tables[0].df.iloc[0].tolist()`.
The output could be:

```
['column1', 'column2', 'column3']
```

Comment: Can you explain me briefly, what happens with the iloc[0] ? And how can I get single full column with all the records into a list? Thank you.

Comment: As you can see in Pandas docs (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), with `iloc[0]` you get the first row, which is a series. With `tolist()` method (see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html), you transform the series into a list. Please accept my answer, if it useful for you.